# Magento 2 how to make sticky navigation top menu for frontend?

Tags: magento2

I am using **Magento2** and I need to make **header sticky** for the frontend .how can I make header sticky?
When user scroll page then header should be sticky at the top, how we can do this? this code should apply for desktop view only not for a mobile and   iPad view.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it works in magento 2.3.5 too ? Because it seams there are different folders an structure. Also in back office content- config- header there are a field to add code for the header. Can works if I add there ?

Answer (score 5):

in header.phtml in your theme add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([ "jquery" ], function($){
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        var height = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(height  > 150 && windowsize >= 768) {
                $('your header class').addClass('fixed-menu');
            }else{
                $('your header class').removeClass('fixed-menu');
            }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fixed-menu{ 
        animation-duration: .45s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-name: fadeInDown;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 100% ;
        top:0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccccb3;
    }
</style>
```

hope this will helps you.

Comment: Can you provide exact path ? I add in the header.phtml. but its not working for me

Comment: <your_theme>/Magento_theme/templates/html/header.phtml . 
If you do not have this file, override it.

Comment: thank you so much . its work for me.

Comment: please accept my answer to helps other dev.

Comment: yes sure i will do..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the custom CSS in your stylesheet if its not already there.
Here is sample example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp
Hope this will help?
Else comment your link I will share the exact CSS code for you.